# Java objects without creating instance

Tags: java, expression, instance, initializer

I recently started learning java and i am trying to understand How is it possible  to equalize a reference object to a variable or method without creating instance, like

Example:

```
class A {

    View  v; 
    v = [someMethod();/variable;]
    // not necessarily view class
}
```

Comment: you can't. Besides that, there are two reasons why your code will not compile.

Comment: To me it is not clear what you are asking. What do you expect this line to do? `v = [someMethod();/variable;]`

Comment: The same way you can point your finger at an existing house without building a new house to point at.

Comment: Its not equalising, in the line ```v = [someMethod();/variable;]``` you are assigning a value to a variable. In case of method, you will assign the value returned from the method to the variable v.

Comment: the method must be returning a reference to `View` or `null` if none should be returned; same for variable. so inside the method there can be a `new` statement or it is getting the reference from somewhere else (calling another method itself); or, the variable, can have been initialized somewhere else to a reference to `new` instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
View w = <expression>;
```

where [`<expression>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8) may create [a new instance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-15.html#jls-ClassInstanceCreationExpression) of `View` or may be evaluated to a reference to the object that already been created at some point in the past.

For instance,

```
Integer i = Integer.valueOf(0);
```

returns the same object for `0` that was created when the `Integer` class was loaded into the JVM.

Answer (score 1):

You can equalize reference to static methods without creating instance, for example you can write:

```
double x = 48;

double random = Math.abs(x);
```

It is possible because the method by itself is static, **it was created when you import** :

```
import java.lang.Math;
```